# Opening a socket in Kali Linux using bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, kali-linux, socket

I know how to open a TCP or UDP socket in Ubuntu, with the following command :

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/google.com/80
```

for example:

we can open a TCP socket on port 80, but in Kali Linux there's no **tcp directory** to be opened by the **exec** command.

1. Could anyone show me the way to open a socket in Kali Linux ?
2. Is there any better or more standard way to open a TCP/UDP socket using bash (script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question doesn't actually depend on `/dev/tcp` existing on a filesystem.  Rather, it is a feature of Bash itself.  For example, if you write a simple HTTP request to file descriptor 3 in your example, you should get a response:

```
> ls /dev/tcp ls: /dev/tcp: No such file or directory
> exec 3<>/dev/tcp/google.com/80
> echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\r" >&3
> cat <&3 
HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; 
charset=UTF-8 
[...SNIP...]
```

If this doesn't work in your shell, it is possible that the default shell you are using doesn't have this particular feature.

Other popular ways of making TCP/UDP connections inside shell scripts include the [`netcat`](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/) and [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) utilities.